# Can I define a union type linking parameters and responses together?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to define a type that can be used by functions to inform callers that an input parameter of a given type leads to its corresponding output type.

So for example, something like this:

```js
type ResponseMap =
  { requestPath: "/user/", response: UserData } |
  { requestPath: "/posts/", response: PostData };

async function getRequest<Value extends ResponseMap>(
  path: Value["requestPath"]
): Promise<Value["response"] | undefined> {
  const response = await fetch(path);
  return response.json();
}

// Currently errors because `PostData` can't be
// assigned to `UserData | undefined`
const response: UserData | undefined = await getRequest("/user/");
```

[Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgEQIbFVAvFA3lUSALigCIBXBRUqAXwG4AoQ6ABQHs5g0Ns8DwEEqTCdgNBo2aCoAJQhxRAOwQBZVGGyMo-RBACO5BcFboAFsID0lJJdIAaKHsXsVQ2FR6ZaUAD7bdAyMuU2ALMktRLjg7R2dlBBIOLi86JkZUOBAlAGMoADNyXOAAS1coAHMIYHlDYwAeADVUABsjKAgAD2AIJQATODkFBIh1MAA+AAowcxJmtogAbVI9OpDzUgBdAEokxHYAWxKEJtajZfjXBC2-KCK+iHySpQg+8bwAnKvgJ2Gr6BwqAA7qgSj98tUcmZpuZtkwdHpgOREEpfi43AA6ABWcFckzhjFoUksligAGFkXolMAWiAOoh9og4IwqjUgsZJqRrFQ7NsMWFepM+uhMFh3rgAjoviofogSPAkKlfHd+o9nq8+MKMExaASgA)

Now, I know I can achieve something like this with function overloads, but I want to reuse `ResponseMap` in other functions as well. Is that possible in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, just need to get and extract the right type:

```
type ResponseMap =
  { requestPath: "user", response: UserData } |
  { requestPath: "posts", response: PostData };

type GetResponseType<Path> = Path extends `/${infer Type}/${string}` ? Extract<ResponseMap, { requestPath: Type }>["response"] : never;
```

Now even paths like `/user/123` will also work!

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/werPBN)

Comment: Woah! That's some next-level type wizardry right there - but it does exactly what I need it to, thanks!